# Deleting photos on google photos backup folder

Tags: video, photos, google-photos

I have installed google photos backup on my machine. If I delete photos/videos on google photos backup folder, does it will also delete those photos/videos on Google Plus ?

I've tried to find the answer on google support but didn't found

Thanks

Comment: I have the same question - did you find an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it will not delete your photos/videos from Google Photos if you delete the Backup folder.

**Remember:** It's about Google Photos Backup, not Google Drive.